# Run an ARIMA model by group

Tags: r, arima

I have a number of groups with monthly data from 2010 to 2016. It's over 80 groups. I succesfully ran an ARIMA model with the montly data but with the sales data summed up (without groups).

Now I'd like to compare the performance with a per group model that runs an ARIMA model for each group and maybe later consider another type of grouping (geographical location, clustering, etc.)

I ran my original model with the following code:

```
        Datos <- read.csv("C:/Users/borja.sanz/Desktop/Borja/Forecasting/V`enter code here`entas/Datos para Forecast.csv")
        options(scipen=999)
        library(lubridate)
        Datos$Fecha = dmy(Datos$Fecha)

        #Declare time series
        tsDatos<-ts(Datos$VentaLocal,start = c(2010,1),frequency = 12)
        plot(tsDatos)
        library(forecast)
        library(dplyr)

        #AutoArima Model
        m_aa = auto.arima(tsDatos)
        f_aa = forecast(m_aa, h=36)
        plot(f_aa)

#Create the forecasts along with the lower and upper bound
    forecast_df = data.frame(prediction=f_aa$mean,
                             abajo=f_aa$lower[,2],
                             arriba=f_aa$upper[,2],
                             date=last_date + seq(1/12, 3, by=1/12))
    forecast_df
```

This is how my data looks like:

```
       Group    Year    Month   Date    Sales
1   2010    1   1/01/2010   134536.625
1   2010    2   1/02/2010   117506.625
1   2010    3   1/03/2010   132153.75
1   2010    4   1/04/2010   129723.125
1   2010    5   1/05/2010   135834.5
1   2010    6   1/06/2010   130115.375
1   2010    7   1/07/2010   144716
1   2010    8   1/08/2010   137195
1   2010    9   1/09/2010   137522.875
1   2010    10  1/10/2010   187063
1   2010    11  1/11/2010   162002.75
1   2010    12  1/12/2010   262297.375
1   2011    1   1/01/2011   177291.25
1   2011    2   1/02/2011   154816
1   2011    3   1/03/2011   171231.125
1   2011    4   1/04/2011   217717
1   2011    5   1/05/2011   178767.75
1   2011    6   1/06/2011   180817.75
1   2011    7   1/07/2011   216927.125
1   2011    8   1/08/2011   204509.125
1   2011    9   1/09/2011   199449.5
1   2011    10  1/10/2011   243812.125
1   2011    11  1/11/2011   232135.875
1   2011    12  1/12/2011   330854.75
1   2012    1   1/01/2012   217123.875
1   2012    2   1/02/2012   200558
1   2012    3   1/03/2012   215689.5
1   2012    4   1/04/2012   245500.25
1   2012    5   1/05/2012   219687.25
1   2012    6   1/06/2012   243345.625
1   2012    7   1/07/2012   249042
1   2012    8   1/08/2012   198443.75
1   2012    9   1/09/2012   209157.375
1   2012    10  1/10/2012   234089
1   2012    11  1/11/2012   237531
1   2012    12  1/12/2012   365301.25
1   2013    1   1/01/2013   211129.375
1   2013    2   1/02/2013   185249.625
1   2013    3   1/03/2013   256565.625
1   2013    4   1/04/2013   183549.5
1   2013    5   1/05/2013   189698.25
1   2013    6   1/06/2013   207955.625
1   2013    7   1/07/2013   230764.125
1   2013    8   1/08/2013   212551.625
1   2013    9   1/09/2013   201329.5
1   2013    10  1/10/2013   242745.125
1   2013    11  1/11/2013   261893.375
1   2013    12  1/12/2013   418313.25
1   2014    1   1/01/2014   205532.75
1   2014    2   1/02/2014   170487.75
1   2014    3   1/03/2014   196077
1   2014    4   1/04/2014   221760.875
1   2014    5   1/05/2014   198185
1   2014    6   1/06/2014   204919.25
1   2014    7   1/07/2014   218972.75
1   2014    8   1/08/2014   221439.875
1   2014    9   1/09/2014   195888.375
1   2014    10  1/10/2014   234595.75
1   2014    11  1/11/2014   259712.875
1   2014    12  1/12/2014   355691.875
1   2015    1   1/01/2015   205156.25
1   2015    2   1/02/2015   185358.875
1   2015    3   1/03/2015   218555.75
1   2015    4   1/04/2015   204233.625
1   2015    5   1/05/2015   212160.625
1   2015    6   1/06/2015   207217.25
1   2015    7   1/07/2015   225723.75
1   2015    8   1/08/2015   205902.625
1   2015    9   1/09/2015   196940.625
1   2015    10  1/10/2015   250916
1   2015    11  1/11/2015   236835.125
1   2015    12  1/12/2015   358327.625
2   2010    1   1/01/2010   227175.875
2   2010    2   1/02/2010   205042
2   2010    3   1/03/2010   239206.375
2   2010    4   1/04/2010   212059.875
2   2010    5   1/05/2010   232789
2   2010    6   1/06/2010   247876.125
2   2010    7   1/07/2010   278557
2   2010    8   1/08/2010   270410.125
2   2010    9   1/09/2010   251060.375
2   2010    10  1/10/2010   302738.625
2   2010    11  1/11/2010   266869.75
2   2010    12  1/12/2010   272978.75
2   2011    1   1/01/2011   238614.5
2   2011    2   1/02/2011   224240.375
2   2011    3   1/03/2011   245457.375
2   2011    4   1/04/2011   238583.5
2   2011    5   1/05/2011   252392.75
2   2011    6   1/06/2011   256749.5
2   2011    7   1/07/2011   264736.125
2   2011    8   1/08/2011   256414
2   2011    9   1/09/2011   242335.125
2   2011    10  1/10/2011   305224.75
2   2011    11  1/11/2011   289199.875
2   2011    12  1/12/2011   281807.75
2   2012    1   1/01/2012   244886.125
2   2012    2   1/02/2012   232062.375
2   2012    3   1/03/2012   264991.75
2   2012    4   1/04/2012   232750.5
2   2012    5   1/05/2012   248498.375
2   2012    6   1/06/2012   264290.875
2   2012    7   1/07/2012   272689.75
2   2012    8   1/08/2012   260441.25
2   2012    9   1/09/2012   251852.375
2   2012    10  1/10/2012   305929.625
2   2012    11  1/11/2012   276711.625
2   2012    12  1/12/2012   278672.875
2   2013    1   1/01/2013   242613.875
2   2013    2   1/02/2013   227575.75
2   2013    3   1/03/2013   250318.875
2   2013    4   1/04/2013   250150.375
2   2013    5   1/05/2013   258467.25
2   2013    6   1/06/2013   261359.25
2   2013    7   1/07/2013   279113.75
2   2013    8   1/08/2013   258699
2   2013    9   1/09/2013   244841.375
2   2013    10  1/10/2013   308197.25
2   2013    11  1/11/2013   284195.5
2   2013    12  1/12/2013   287718.75
2   2014    1   1/01/2014   239510.375
2   2014    2   1/02/2014   216338.125
2   2014    3   1/03/2014   245626.75
2   2014    4   1/04/2014   230619.875
2   2014    5   1/05/2014   251758.875
2   2014    6   1/06/2014   254946.75
2   2014    7   1/07/2014   276268.75
2   2014    8   1/08/2014   266151.75
2   2014    9   1/09/2014   245859.375
2   2014    10  1/10/2014   317797.5
2   2014    11  1/11/2014   283786.625
2   2014    12  1/12/2014   289767.875
2   2015    1   1/01/2015   244008
2   2015    2   1/02/2015   228638
2   2015    3   1/03/2015   260056
2   2015    4   1/04/2015   232560.875
2   2015    5   1/05/2015   252642.125
2   2015    6   1/06/2015   249018.5
2   2015    7   1/07/2015   278113.125
2   2015    8   1/08/2015   255851
2   2015    9   1/09/2015   263046.625
2   2015    10  1/10/2015   344240.75
2   2015    11  1/11/2015   295486.125
2   2015    12  1/12/2015   293499.375
```

I only included two groups in the sample. I would like to use a function like one of the apply (tapply, lapply, sapply, etc.) that can run an AUTO.ARIMA model per group. Then I would like to obtain the forecast for each group for x number of months and also if I could visualize the model coefficients.

Comment: Try the hts package.

Comment: Are you just asking how this could be coded? That would be off-topic here.

Comment: I'm also asking if this is makes sense from a statistical point of view